# To responsive horizontal, scrolling navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with responsive menu. I'm trying to create horizontal scrolling menu on screen change (responsive).

This is how menu looks on pc screen (full width):
[image]

This is how menu looks on mobile device screen:
[image]

I need the bar to scroll right, without those Scrollbars. Is there a way to do this?

```
<div class="menu">
    <nav class="infobar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-left">
                <div class="col-min">
                    <p>Example</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-min">
                    <p>Example</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-min">
                    <p>Example</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-min">
                    <p>Example</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-min">
                    <p>Example</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-min">
                    <p>Example</p>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

MAIN CSS

```
.infobar {
 width: 100%;
 background: #f7f7f7;
 height: 80px;
border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
border-radius: 0;

.col-min {
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 80px;
    background: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #ededed;
    border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    left: 1px;
    float: left;
}
```

MOBILE CSS

```
.infobar {
    min-width:100%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hide;    
}

.menu .nav {
    margin-left: -5px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/94f1d5v5/

https://jsfiddle.net/94f1d5v5/1/

Comment: Just to confirm, you want only the navigation to scroll??

Answer (score 1):

Use perfect-scroll for auto-hiding scrollbar and display: flex for better experience.

```
.nav {
   display: flex;
   padding: 24px
}
```

I make small refactoring [playcode.io/8](http://playcode.io/8?tabs=app.html&style.less&output)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

instead of

```
overflow-y: hide
```

and as for stylizing the scrollbars, you can use the following classes:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              {}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       {}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        {}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        {}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       {}
::-webkit-resizer                {}
```

More info [here](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)